# Link to another table to get name with inner join

Tags: mysql, database, inner-join

The following code shows the max date for an item and all works well.

```
    SELECT 
    pricing_id, pricing.field, pricing.region, price, max_date
FROM
    pricing
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        field, MAX(end_date) AS 'max_date'
    FROM
        pricing, regions
    GROUP BY field) AS tmptable ON tmptable.max_date = pricing.end_date
        AND tmptable.field = pricing.field
ORDER BY region, pricing.field
```

I am trying to pull region name from regions.region_name to replace the pricing.region column which just shows the ID. I have tried the usual where clause to join tables and display the descriptive name but it breaks it.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

John

Comment: Your from clause in the subselect has both pricing and regions. Shouldn't that just be regions?

Comment: Could you please also describe what's the attempt with the sub-query there? Which table is the `end_date` in and why are both tables needed to find the `MAX(end_date)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to select region_name from the regions table

somthing like

```
SELECT 
pricing_id, pricing.field, tmptable.region_name , price, max_date
FROM
pricing
    INNER JOIN
(SELECT 
   region_name , field, MAX(end_date) AS 'max_date'
FROM
    pricing, regions
GROUP BY field) AS tmptable ON tmptable.max_date = pricing.end_date
    AND tmptable.field = pricing.field
ORDER BY region, pricing.field
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table is similar in setup this should work. I am making an assumption that you don't want to try to find it in the sub-select which seems like more work than required. Instead I added it as a LEFT JOIN and changed the rest of the query around to match.

```
SELECT 
    pricing_id, pricing.field, r.region_name, price, max_date
FROM
    pricing
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        field, MAX(end_date) AS 'max_date'
    FROM
        pricing
    GROUP BY field) AS tmptable ON tmptable.max_date = pricing.end_date
        AND tmptable.field = pricing.field
LEFT JOIN regions r ON r.id = pricing.region
ORDER BY r.region_name, pricing.field
```